# Weapon damage and spells?

Tags: divinity-original-sin

Does a weapon's damage affect the damage of air, earth, water, witchcraft or fire spells?

Does a weapon's elemental type affect the damage of air, earth, water, witchcraft or fire spells?

Answer (score 2):

A weapons damage (elemental or otherwise) doesn't affect other damage from spells, whether that's a status (burning, poisoned, etc.) or an incoming spell attack.

Weapons with elemental damage will list the damage in the item tooltip, which pops up when hovering your cursor over the item in the inventory.  The weapons are not limited to an "elemental type", but can deal elemental damage on top of physical damage.

You can add additional elemental damage types or strengthen existing elemental damage on a weapon by having a character with +5 crafting mix an elemental essence with the weapon.  Note that you can only ever use one elemental essence on a weapon - if you try using more, they will only override the existing elemental essence damage (but not the base elemental damage) on the weapon.

Be careful with mixing too many elemental damage types - some enemies heal from a specific elemental damage.  If you have three different elemental damage types on a weapon, you may end up partially healing some enemies.